# find string and call different script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find the text  from the file and need to call different batch file if string found. When I tried this code nothing happens. I don't know where am I going wrong. 
Here is the code.

```
@echo off
>nul find "BARNSLEY INTERCHANGE" location.txt && (
  call "barnsleyinterchange.bat"
) || (
   >nul find "DONCASTER INTERCHANGE" location.txt && (
      call "doncasterinterchange.bat"
   ) || (
      >nul find "CRYSTAL PEAKS" location.txt && (
         call "crystalpeaks.bat"
      ) || (
         >nul find "MIDDLEWOOD PARK RIDE" location.txt && (
            call "middlewoodpr.bat"
         ) || (
            >nul find "MEADOWHALL INTERCHANGE" location.txt && (
               call "meadowhallinterchange.bat"
            ) || (
               >nul find "ROTHERHAM INTERCHANGE" location.txt && (
                  call "rotherhaminterchange.bat"
               ) || (
                  >nul find "SHEFFIELD INTERCHANGE" location.txt && (
                     call "sheffieldinterchange.bat"
                  ) || (
                     echo "Syntax" was NOT found.
)))))))
pause
```

Comment: Don't you want to try a totally different approach?

Comment: yes i could but which way can i go for it.

Comment: Put the search terms and batch file names into a TXT file with delimiters. Look at the help of the `for` command. Read the TXT file, split with `delims=;`. If you have trouble with the `for` command, search here on SO again, do not ask a new question. I have answered lots of `for` related questions already. The answer is out there already.

Answer (score 1):

While you try the suggestion of @ThomasW (and i agree with him, its `for` idea will be the better or at least the easier to maintain), this is an alternative to your code, same idea, just a little simplified

```
@echo off

    >nul find "BARNSLEY INTERCHANGE"   location.txt  && ( call "barnsleyinterchange.bat"    & goto out )
    >nul find "DONCASTER INTERCHANGE"  location.txt  && ( call "doncasterinterchange.bat"   & goto out )
    >nul find "CRYSTAL PEAKS"          location.txt  && ( call "crystalpeaks.bat"           & goto out )
    >nul find "MIDDLEWOOD PARK RIDE"   location.txt  && ( call "middlewoodpr.bat"           & goto out )
    >nul find "MEADOWHALL INTERCHANGE" location.txt  && ( call "meadowhallinterchange.bat"  & goto out )
    >nul find "ROTHERHAM INTERCHANGE"  location.txt  && ( call "rotherhaminterchange.bat"   & goto out )
    >nul find "SHEFFIELD INTERCHANGE"  location.txt  && ( call "sheffieldinterchange.bat"   & goto out )

    echo "Syntax" was NOT found.

:out
    pause
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for an external file to use the FOR technique:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (
  "BARNSLEY INTERCHANGE|barnsleyinterchange.bat"
  "DONCASTER INTERCHANGE|doncasterinterchange.bat"
  "CRYSTAL PEAKS|crystalpeaks.bat"
  "MIDDLEWOOD PARK RIDE|middlewoodpr.bat"
  "MEADOWHALL INTERCHANGE|meadowhallinterchange.bat"
  "ROTHERHAM INTERCHANGE|rotherhaminterchange.bat"
  "SHEFFIELD INTERCHANGE|sheffieldinterchange.bat"
) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%B in (%%A) do (
  >nul find "%%~nB" location.txt && (
    call "%%C"
    goto :done
  )
)
echo "Syntax" was NOT found.

:done
pause
```

Or, if you rename your batch files to match your search terms, then:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (
  "BARNSLEY INTERCHANGE"
  "DONCASTER INTERCHANGE"
  "CRYSTAL PEAKS"
  "MIDDLEWOOD PARK RIDE"
  "MEADOWHALL INTERCHANGE"
  "ROTHERHAM INTERCHANGE"
  "SHEFFIELD INTERCHANGE"
) do >nul find "%%~A" location.txt && (
    call "%%~A.bat"
    goto :done
  )
)
echo "Syntax" was NOT found.

:done
pause
```